# How can I update a WordpPress page created with Elementor by updating the database?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, elementor

I have a WordPress page created with Elementor plugin.

This page contains a section with a paragraph like this:

```
<p>AAAAA</p>
```

I want to update the content of this page from the database.

This is what I tried:

I searched in the `wp_posts` table all rows where `post_content` contains `<p>AAAAA</p>` and updated this value with this value:

```
<p>BBBBB</p>
```

I used phpMyAdmin to do that.

However, if I force refresh the browser where I see this WordPress page, I still see `AAAAA` instead of `BBBBB`.

Only if I manually edit the page content with Elementor I can see the changes (and also the Db is updated).

How can I update the Elementor page by updating the database?

Comment: I find out that the elementor page contents are stored in the table `wp_postmeta`. Now I am looking for a way to convert an HTML page into an Elementor JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update elementor meta value:

UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = '/UPDATED VALUE HERE/' WHERE `meta_key` = "_elementor_data"